# Adding Columns to a Table

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table with 10 columns.  For some reason, when I add an 11th column, the table no longer compiles.

Below is, I believe, a minimum working example.

Specifically, the table works with

```
 \begin{tabular}{l*9{c}}
```

but it does not work with

```
 \begin{tabular}{l*10{c}}
```

Note that the following ONLY compiles because it is the version with the 9 rather than the 10.  I would like for it to have the 10 so I can insert an extra column.

My tables begin as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*10{c}}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) \\  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've edited the MWE here down to an absolute minimum to show the issue: this should help other uses see what is going on. In particular, the issue is independent of `tabularx`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that the `*` syntax takes a single argument: it does not keep 'looking' for a number. So instead of

```
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{l*10{c}}
```

you need

```
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{l*{10}{c}}
```

Notice the braces around the `10`.

Comment: Just for clarification. Numbers less than 10 work without the braces because they get parsed as numbers, but those with more digits fail? This suggested I need quite a different wetware parser for Latex.

Comment: @DWin Standard TeX argument grabbing: a `<balanced text>` so either a single token or one or more tokens in a brace group.

Comment: So a liberal use of braces in TeX is like a liberal use of parentheses in situations where you are not sure of operator precedence in other languages.